# Amazon link hacking

Tags: bug, status-completed, amazon

The Stack Exchange software rewrites Amazon URLs to benefit from an affiliate programme. Unfortunately, this seems to be broken at present. E.g. http:// www.amazon.co.uk/UMBRELLA-COVER-LARGE-PERFECT-SUMMER/dp/B003O2JW64 is becoming [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003O2JW64) which gives a 404.

Comment: From the looks of it, it seems to be rewriting amazon.co.uk to amazon.com. Probably broken for all non-US links.

Comment: I don't think it is broken for all international links: Consider this. http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/16?m=2036888#2036888. Keep in mind that this counterexample is chat and older, there could have been changes or differences between chat and main.

Comment: We're taking a look...it certainly is a bug, will update this as soon as we have a plan to handle these.

Comment: See [this MSO post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106294/how-can-we-link-to-products-that-exist-on-amazon-co-uk-but-not-amazon-com-withou).  It is broken only for products that don't exist on the US site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rewriting will no longer touch Amazon urls that aren't to the US .com site.